What are the allowed values / source spec for umlRole in a metaconstraint?
In a UML definition of a metamodel it is possible to define metaconstraints e.g.
<<metaconstraint>> umlRole="classifier"
<<metaconstraint>> umlRole = "class"

amongst other things.
Where is the allowed set of values specified? In what OMG specification does this appear? I can't see it in the UML 2.5.1 specification (formal/2017-12-05)

Well, if you didn't find it in the specification, where did you? I have never heard of metaconstraints. Of course, a constraint on a metaclass is possible - and used quite frequently in the specification. But this is simply a constraint.

Maybe you got this from EA?
